# Maximum $\int_{0}^{y}\sqrt{x^4+\left(y-y^2\right)^2}dx$ where $y\in \left[0,1\right]$?

Tags: real-analysis

How find maximum this integral $$\int_{0}^{y}\sqrt{x^4+\left(y-y^2\right)^2}dx$$ where $y\in \left[0,1\right]$?

Comment: Could the fundamental theorem of calculus be of some help ?

Comment: Not really, you still have a nasty integral left over because $y$ is inside the integral too.

Comment: It is better to prove that $f(y)$ is an increasing function, hence the maximum $\frac{1}{3}$ is attained in $y=1$.

Comment: ok, how prove $f(y)=\int_{0}^{y}\sqrt{x^4+\left(y-y^2\right)^2}dx$ is an increasing function?

Comment: @piteer: $g(y)=y(1-y)$ is increasing over $I=[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ hence $f$ is increasing over $I$. Can you complete this argument and prove that $f$ is increasing over $[1/2,1]$, too?

Comment: @piteer: notice that it is sufficient to prove that for any $y\in[1/2,1]$ we have $f(y)<f(1)=\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [differentiation under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) we get
\begin{align*}\left(\int_0^y\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}\,dx\right)'&=\int_0^y\frac{2(y-y^2)(1-2y)}{2\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}}dx+\sqrt{y^4+(y-y^2)^2}\\&=\sqrt{y^4+(y-y^2)^2}+\int_0^y\frac{y(1-y)(1-2y)}{\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}}dx,\end{align*}
which is positive for $y\in(0,\frac12)$. Else suppose $y\in(\frac12,1)$, then it's positive if
$$\int_0^y\frac{(2y-1)(y-y^2)}{\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}}dx=-\int_0^y\frac{y(1-y)(1-2y)}{\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}}dx<\sqrt{y^4+(y-y^2)^2}=y\sqrt{y^2+(1-y)^2}.$$
Clearly,
$$\int_0^y\frac{(2y-1)(y-y^2)}{\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}}dx<y\cdot\frac{(2y-1)(y-y^2)}{\sqrt{(y-y^2)^2}}=y(2y-1),$$
so it remains to check that
$$2y-1\le\sqrt{y^2+(1-y)^2}\iff 0\le y^2+(1-y)^2-(2y-1)^2=-2y^2+2y=2y(1-y)$$
So we can conclude the maximum is attained for $y=1$, where it's
$$\int_0^1\sqrt{x^4}\,dx=\int_0^1 x^2\, dx=\frac13.$$

Comment: Whoops, I have just posted a solution that is almost identical to yours, I did not notice you wrote it. Hope you don't mind. (+1), anyway.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Well, that sometimes happens. As long as it's independent, it's perfectly fine, so have a +1 too :)

Answer (score 4):

Since $g(y)=y(1-y)$ is increasing over $I=\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$, so it is $f$. Assume now $y\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]$.

We have:
$$ f'(y)=-\int_{0}^{y}\frac{(y-y^2)(2y-1)}{\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}}dx+\sqrt{y^4+(y-y^2)^2},\tag{1}$$
but in virtue of the mean value theorem:
$$ \int_{0}^{y}\frac{(y-y^2)(2y-1)}{\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}}dx \leq y(2y-1)\tag{2}$$
so it is sufficient to prove that:
$$ y^2+(1-y)^2 \geq (2y-1)^2 \tag{3}$$
for any $y\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]$, to have that $f$ is increasing over $[0,1]$. However, $(3)$ is equivalent to $y(1-y)\geq 0$, that is trivial. This gives that the maximum of $f(y)$ over $[0,1]$ is attained in $y=1$, and the maximum is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

By taking derivative with respect to $y$ and setting it to be equal to $0$ we have :
$$\int_{0}^{y}\frac{(y-y^2)(1-2y)}{\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}}dx+\sqrt{y^4+(y-y^2)^2}=0$$
Hence:
$$\int_{0}^{y}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}}dx=\frac{\sqrt{y^4+(y-y^2)^2}}{(y-y^2)(2y-1)}$$

Comment: ok, and what to do next?

Comment: @piteer: nothing, since equality cannot hold for $y\in[0,1]$. The given function is increasing over $[0,1]$, hence the maximum is attained in the right endpoint, not in a stationary point.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dy}(f(y)) &= \frac{d}{dy} \Bigg(\int_{0}^{y}\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}dx\Bigg) \\&= \int_{0}^{y}\frac{(y -y^2)(1-2y)}{\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}} dx + \sqrt{y^4+(y-y^2)^2} . 1\end{align}$$

Now $$\begin{align}&\int_{0}^{y}\frac{(y -y^2)(1-2y)}{\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}} dx + \sqrt{y^4+(y-y^2)^2} = 0 \\&\Rightarrow \int_{0}^{y}\frac{(y -y^2)(1-2y)}{\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}} dx = - \sqrt{y^4+(y-y^2)^2} \\&\Rightarrow \int_{0}^{y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}} dx = \frac{\sqrt{y^4+(y-y^2)^2}}{(y-y^2)(2y-1)} \end{align}$$

Check the sign of $\frac{d}{dy}f(y)$ to see if the function $f(y)$ is decreasing, increasing.

Comment: Remember this is a condition on $y$, not the solution of the integral.

Comment: You're right, so we can't get any conclusion from that?

Comment: I cannot see an obvious way to derive $f'(y)>0$ from your calculations.

Comment: WolframAlpha solves the integral in terms of an elliptic integral, but I don't know how to solve an equation with elliptic integrals in it.

Comment: @Michael: also because there are no solutions in $[0,1]$. The maximum is achieved in an endpoint, not in a stationary point.